# asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument

Tags: python-3.7, asyncpg

I asyncpg use library for connect to mydb through pool. To execute this code block i get a mistake: **asyncpg.exception.Data Error: invalid input for query argument $10: '2019-12-31' ('str' object has no attribute 'toordinal')**

My code:

```
await db.execute("""
            insert into hs.public.users
            (u_login,.....,u_reg_date)
            values
            ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10)
        """, data ['email'].split('@')[0],....., datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

In my DB, the "u_reg_date" field is of type "date". If you use the {} sign instead of $, then everything works. I would like to know why and what I do wrong, although judging by the documentation I do everything correctly. Thanks. Happy new year and Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` with `datetime.date.today()`.

You need to pass `datetime.date` object instead of string.